# how can i optimize for below query pgsql. here joined two table and result basis implemented auto complete search

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

```
SELECT category, A.tag, description 
from catalog.audience_tag A 
  LEFT JOIN catalog.synonym B on (A.tag = B.tag) 
WHERE (A.category @ 'aaa@*%' 
       OR description ILIKE '%aaa%' 
       or synonyms ILIKE '%aaa%') 
  AND category @ 'Population@*%'  
ORDER BY SORT
```

above the query is used for auto complete search

Comment: Your query cannot use a b-tree index.

Comment: am new to postgres, and here i didn't understand @ purpose, that's the reason i posted here. if you understand above this, plz let me know or kindly give suggestion

Comment: From which table does `category` come from?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: What is the datatype of `A.category`?  Or just share the definition of both tables.